# Star in zone host and Bind with DlZ

Tags: postgresql, dns, bind

I would like to use [DLZ](http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/) with bind and to store dns records in database. At this moment everything works fine, and all zones resolve correctly. But I have zone wih the "star" in the hostname.
For example

```
*.example.com IN A 187.78.67.13
```

How I should put it to database, that  BIND and [DLZ](http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/) driver could point any domain name in `example.com` to `187.78.67.13`

I want that the result of query

```
nslookup anyname.example.com
```

points to  187.78.67.13

ANSWER is:

There is no sollution and also rhere is no problem. That was missunderstanding from me. When in host column where only asterisk '*' everything works ok. But when you try to create record *.p.example.com in zone example.com you should create anothe zone p.example.com and then create record *.p.example.com in new zone.

Comment: This question is unlikely related to PostgreSQL. Also, have you considered asking this over on serverfault.com? You are more likely to find knowledgeable people in that area over there. More details would help too... what have you tried already? What did you put in your database? Are you getting errors? If yes, which ones?

Comment: Thank you, I solved a problem with asterisk in hostname with bind. 
You are right that not a postgresql problem. That Bind and dlz problem.

Comment: It would be nice of you to post the solution as answer and accept it yourself. At least, this way, other people having the same problem will find it.

Comment: There is no sollution and also rhere is no problem. That was missunderstanding from me.  
When in host column where only asterisk '*' everything works ok. But when you try to create record *.p.example.com in zone example.com you should create anothe zone p.example.com and then create record *.p.example.com in new zone.

Comment: You could still post it as an answer. Just in case anyone else runs into this same issue/question. Or delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sollution and also rhere is no problem. That was missunderstanding from me. When in host column where only asterisk '*' everything works ok. But when you try to create record *.p.example.com in zone example.com you should create anothe zone p.example.com and then create record *.p.example.com in new zone.